# AI server crashes when I make a request after adding openAI code

Tags: python, server, openai-api

My python server is crashing every time I try to make a request to it. I recently edited my code.
The original code worked fine:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from pydantic import BaseModel
import uvicorn
import os
import importlib.util
import sys

app = FastAPI()

beep = True

@app.get('/')
def get_func():
        return {'text':'SLClient API active'}, 200

@app.post("/client/")
async def get_body(dat: Request):
        dat = await dat.json()
        global beep
        if beep == True:
                os.system("/usr/bin/beep -f 2000 -l 20")
        try:
                if dat == None:
                        return {'state':'error','e':'No data error'}
                else:
                        if dat['jobid'] == "nobeep":
                                beep = False
                                return {'state':'complete','jobid':dat['jobid']}
                        if dat['jobid'] == "beep":
                                beep = True
                                return {'state':'complete','jobid':dat['jobid']}
                        if dat['jobid'] == "ping":
                                return {'state':'complete','jobid':'0','text':'Pong'}
                        else:
                                return {'state':'complete','jobid':dat['jobid'],'text': dat['text'], 'username':dat['username'],'uid':dat['uid']}
        except Exception as e:
                return {'state':'error','e':str(e)}
```

The new code implements a new script that uses OpenAI.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from pydantic import BaseModel
import uvicorn
import os
import importlib.util
import sys
import responses

app = FastAPI()

beep = True

@app.get('/')
def get_func():
        return {'text':'SLClient API active'}, 200

@app.post("/client/")
async def get_body(dat: Request):
        dat = await dat.json()
        global beep
        if beep == True:
                os.system("/usr/bin/beep -f 2000 -l 20")
        try:
                if dat == None:
                        return {'state':'error','e':'No data error'}
                else:
                        if dat['jobid'] == "nobeep":
                                beep = False
                                return {'state':'complete','jobid':dat['jobid']}
                        if dat['jobid'] == "beep":
                                beep = True
                                return {'state':'complete','jobid':dat['jobid']}
                        if dat['jobid'] == "ping":
                                return {'state':'complete','jobid':'0','text':'Pong'}
                        if dat['jobid'] == "apiTest":
                                try:
                                        responses.chat("test","test")
                                        return {'state':'complete','jobid':'0','text':'No problems'}
                                except Exception as ex:
                                        return {'state':'error','e':str(ex)}
                        else:
                                return {'state':'complete','jobid':dat['jobid'],'text': dat['text'], 'username':dat['username'],'uid':dat['uid']}
        except Exception as e:
                return {'state':'error','e':str(e)}
```

Here is the code for responses.py, which is in the same folder as api.py (the main program)
(API key hidden, in the actual file it is there)

```
import os
import openai

async def chat(prompt, sysmsg):
    openai.api_base = 'https://api.nova-oss.com/v1'
    openai.api_key = """##############################"""
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo",messages=[{"role":"system", "content":sysmsg},{"role":"user", "content":prompt}])
    result=''
    for choice in response.choices:
        result += choice.message.content
    return result
```

With both the original and new code, I am using this to call it:

```
import requests
url = '######################'
response = requests.post(url,json={'jobid':'ping'}).json()
```

The first one worked fine, returning the expected `{'state':'complete','jobid':'0','text':'Pong'}`

The new code doesn't return anything.
On the client side, I get this error

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.68.200', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /client/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000022DCBF01F90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

On the server side, I get this when I look at systemctl status

```
× api.service - Gunicorn instance manager to serve API
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/api.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-10-24 17:28:21 UTC; 12min ago
    Process: 1300 ExecStart=/home/webserver/SLClient/client/bin/gunicorn api:app -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b 0.0.0.0:5000 (code=exited, status=3)
   Main PID: 1300 (code=exited, status=3)
        CPU: 6.767s

Oct 24 17:28:21 sparklink-server gunicorn[1304]: [2023-10-24 17:28:21 +0000] [1304] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1304)
Oct 24 17:28:21 sparklink-server gunicorn[1300]: [2023-10-24 17:28:21 +0000] [1300] [ERROR] Worker (pid:1301) exited with code 3
Oct 24 17:28:21 sparklink-server gunicorn[1300]: [2023-10-24 17:28:21 +0000] [1300] [ERROR] Worker (pid:1304) was sent SIGTERM!
Oct 24 17:28:21 sparklink-server gunicorn[1300]: [2023-10-24 17:28:21 +0000] [1300] [ERROR] Worker (pid:1303) was sent SIGTERM!
Oct 24 17:28:21 sparklink-server gunicorn[1300]: [2023-10-24 17:28:21 +0000] [1300] [ERROR] Worker (pid:1302) was sent SIGTERM!
Oct 24 17:28:21 sparklink-server gunicorn[1300]: [2023-10-24 17:28:21 +0000] [1300] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
Oct 24 17:28:21 sparklink-server gunicorn[1300]: [2023-10-24 17:28:21 +0000] [1300] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
Oct 24 17:28:21 sparklink-server systemd[1]: api.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
Oct 24 17:28:21 sparklink-server systemd[1]: api.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 24 17:28:21 sparklink-server systemd[1]: api.service: Consumed 6.767s CPU time.
```